# RGB lighting on a wireframe in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, wireframe

I'm trying to make a wire frame around a box have RGB colors emitting from it, well they don't have to emit, just 'glow' with the colors Red Green and Blue, RGB. it's for a small project, I wan't a RGB lighting strip kind of like they show on Strix boxes for graphics cards. I'm doing all this in the Cycles engine

Comment: Please add reference images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly: You are trying to do something like this

[image]

1. Create cube (or leave default cube when starting Blender)
2. Duplicate it (Shift + D)
3. Scale it up a little bigger
4. Subdivide the cube for more wire frame lines
5. Under modifier tab choose wireframe
6. For the wireframe materials copy the below set up.

[image]

7. After rendering the image go to your compositor and add a glare node like below. I normally do compositing in Photoshop and After Effects so I am not to good with Blender Compositor but this should be you semi close.

[image]

8. You can also add a streak node to make it look more like Strix

EDIT: IF you want to animate it

There are a few ways to do this, I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do but you can add a mapping node and animate the position by hitting "i" for the keyframes.

[image]

Comment: this worked great! thanks, but now I'm wondering how to make this animated, so the lights go across it.

Comment: Well there are a few ways to do this, I edited the answer to include a very simple way. If you want to get more complex I would watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2WTH016rfk

Comment: Thank you so much my dude, ill be sure to post the end result