# Shining reflection

Tags: volumetrics

How can I add a very slight "glowy" shine on places where light is directly  pointing at. Just like in real life. I always need to do it with photoshop afterwards, but in one of Gleb Alexandrovs renderings I cann see that he have done it already in his Rendering. Unfortunately I cant find a tutorial so far. 
Let me show you what I am aiming for. 
[image]
On Top you see the render result and below I have added the "glow" with photoshop. I think this is more realistic. Is there a way to achieve this effect immediately into blender? Maybe even showing in the rendered view :,) Please.

Best regards
Frece

Comment: In Compositing use the Glare Node: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/filter/glare.html Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles/34383#34383

Comment: Isn't there a specifivc mininal node construct for exactly my pupose?

Comment: What is "mininal node construct"?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see any difference between the two images. But I would use the Principled Shader and lean towards roughness rather than shiny. That will help spread the highlight out. The size and type of light source will have an impact as well.

Comment: In this link there is my answer showing a "minimal node setup" for the glare node https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94082/rgb-lighting-on-a-wireframe-in-cycles/94096#94096

Comment: @user48469 to see glowing effect while rendering in Cycles add volumetric nodes - Volume Absorbtion and/or Volume Scatter. This will heavily increase amount of time to render. That's why this is often done with post-processing with Glare node as already suggested. Note also in Eevee render engine available in 2.8 this can be previewed in viewport in real time.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender/15704#15704

Comment: @cegaton your link is exactly what I have looked for. I use it in all my renderings now. Thank you SOOO much! (I want to add a discription of how to use it properly in this section here. I just need some time)